# How to use I2C in U-Boot SPL

Tags: i2c, u-boot

I was able to use the I2C commands from within U-Boot to control my I2C device:

- Configured the Processor GPIOs for the I2C bus in device tree
- Enabled the I2C bus in device tree
- Added my device to the I2C bus in device tree
- Wrote my script into a U-Boot variable
- Run my script

Now I want to do the same from within the U-Boot SPL. I extended `int board_early_init_f(void)` in `board.c` for my hardware. The debug output is printed at run time. But the I2C device is not found.

How do I review whether the I2C bus is using the right GPIOs and whether my device is configured right?

```
static int i2c_get_dev(uint bus_num, uint dev_num, struct udevice **i2c_dev)
{
    int ret;

    if (!i2c_led_bus) {
        ret = uclass_get_device_by_seq(UCLASS_I2C, bus_num, &i2c_led_bus);
        if (ret) {
            printf("I2C bus %i not found (%d)\n", dev_num, ret);
            return -ENODEV;
        }
    }

    return i2c_get_chip(i2c_led_bus, dev_num, bus_num, i2c_dev);
}
#endif

static int i2c_enable_leds(void)
{
    log_info("i2c_enable_leds\n");
    const uint  bus_num = 1;    // i2c bus
    const uint  dev_num = 0x28;     // i2c chip address
    const uint  dev_addr = 0x00;    // write all bytes in one junk from start
    const uint  dev_addr_len = 1;
    int     ret;
    const uint  cmd_len = 29;       // cmd_len is the number of bytes.
    uchar   cmd[29] = {
        0x40, 0x3c, // init
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // unused
        0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, // set intensitiy to max
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // unused
        0xff, 0x00, 0x00, // RGB LED
        0xff, 0x00, 0x00 // RGB LED
    };
#if CONFIG_IS_ENABLED(DM_I2C)
    struct udevice *i2c_dev;
    struct dm_i2c_chip *i2c_chip;
#endif

#if CONFIG_IS_ENABLED(DM_I2C)
    ret = i2c_get_dev(bus_num, dev_num, &i2c_dev);
    if (!ret)
        ret = i2c_set_chip_offset_len(i2c_dev, dev_addr_len);
    if (ret) {
        log_err("Failed to write to 0x28 (%d)\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    i2c_chip = dev_get_parent_plat(i2c_dev);
    if (!i2c_chip) {
        log_err("Failed to write to 0x28 (%d)\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
#endif

#if CONFIG_IS_ENABLED(DM_I2C)
        i2c_chip->flags &= ~DM_I2C_CHIP_WR_ADDRESS;
        ret = dm_i2c_write(i2c_dev, dev_addr, cmd, cmd_len);
#else
        ret = i2c_write(dev_num, dev_addr, dev_addr_len, cmd, cmd_len);
#endif
        if (ret)
            log_err("Failed to write to 0x28 (%d)\n", ret);

    return 0;
}
```

```
int board_early_init_f(void)
{
    i2c_enable_leds();

    return 0;
}
```